# What's the proper way to create `viewing window` in vim plugins?

Tags: vim

I am writing a plugin and there are some data(stored in a file) that I want to display to users when users toggle this feature.

What is the proper way to implement this? I guess I could use `:new` or ':view` to display the file as a buffer, are there better ways to do it?

I am thinking something similar to the window generated by`:help`, however I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: `:help` is not "a popup". It's rather a sort of `:new`. Please, clarify your question.

Comment: @Matt I probably used the wrong term. I want a window similar to `:help`. All I want is a window to present some text to users.

Comment: Why not to write a help file then?

Comment: There’s also preview windows, actual popups, scratch buffers... search for any of those and you have starting points

Comment: I guess my question is more like, I don't want the content that I am showing to be editable. I really like popup because it allows me to pass a string, however it's only available in 8.2. Preview window seems have to load a buffer, Can I make it also not editable?